# Dealing with files in PSUnit

Tags: powershell, tdd, powershell-2.0, fileinfo, psunit

I'm writing a Powershell script which is going to go out into a client's current source control system and do a mass rename on all of the files so that they follow a new naming convention.

Being the diligent TDD developer that I am, I started with putting together a PSUnit test case. At first I was thinking that I would pass in a string to my function for the file name (along with a couple of other relevant parameters) and then return a string. Then it occurred to me that I am going to need to break apart the file name into an extension and a base name. Since System.IO.FileInfo already has that functionality, I thought why not just pass in a file object instead of a string?

If I do that however, then I don't see how I can write my PSUnit test without it being reliant on an external resource (in this case, the file must exist for me to get the FileInfo object - or does it?).

Is there a "clean" way to handle this? How are others approaching these issues?

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: darn it ;) I was answer that ClearCase question of yours on the 'setview' part. What did you actually found?

Comment: I found that I'm an idiot who changed a variable name in one place, but not another. ;)  The setview thing I still didn't find a solution for though. That just fixed the problem of not being able to change the file name.

Comment: but setview is just a way to have a shortcut for dynamic views on Unix. On Windows, you would use a drive letter by mapping a folder to it with the simple (non-ClearCase) Windows command `subst` (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-a-drive-letter-to-a-folder-the-easy-way-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is: Be pragmatic and pass in the base name and extension as two separate strings. For convenience reasons, you can provide an overload that accepts a `FileInfo`.